# masks pockets of weakness

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "masks pockets of weakness" as "stops entering into the pockets of the poor or vulnerable."  Am I on the right track?

> The overall resilience of China’s economy, though, **masks pockets of weakness**.
> Source: NYTimes   [Most Major Economies Are Shrinking. Not China’s.](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/17/business/china-economy-gdp.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means “conceals areas of weaknesses”. The next paragraph goes on to list some weak aspects of China’s economy, starting with “jobs... have been scarce for recent college graduates with little experience”.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the wrong track.

A mask hides the wearer's face. The overall strength of China's economy hides the fact that there are weak spots in it (the economy).

Comment: You're describing "mask" as a noun. In this sentence "[mask](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mask)" is used as a verb meaning *To make indistinct or difficult to perceive*, not to disguise or cover up. I think it does not help a learner to confuse the two meanings.

Comment: @ColleenV - I know perfectly well that _mask_ is a verb here, but may I draw your attention to Oxford's definition: _conceal (something) from view.
"the poplars masked a factory"_ I wanted to make it clear to the OP that the meaning was _hide_ and not _block_.

Comment: But it’s not being used as *The hacker masked their identity by spoofing their IP address.*, it’s being used in the *The hot spices masked the gaminess of the meat.* sense. There’s a difference, and I think if a learner is reading the NY Times they’re probably interested in it. There are multiple definitions for mask as a verb, I think you picked the wrong one.

Comment: @ColleenV We will have to agree to differ.

Comment: @ColleenV: I think Kate is on the right track here. Unless I'm much mistaken (I haven't checked), the ***noun*** is the "original, base" term here. It doesn't really matter exactly *why* someone might wear a mask (restrict virus transmission, hide identify,...). It just seems to me that learners should be made aware of the fact of there being a connection between that underlying noun and the actual *verb* usage in the Q. Next time, they might be better able to work out the nature of any such connection for themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I disagree that an advanced learner benefits by smearing together the meaning of covering a face with a mask (completely obscuring parts of it), and some characteristic of the economy overpowering other aspects making it difficult (but not impossible) to perceive "pockets of weakness". Would it help to also talk about "masking tape"? I don't think so. I think when meanings are very nuanced, it does a learner a disservice to confuse one sense of the word with the other.

Comment: @ColleenV: Well, as Kate says, perhaps we also will have to agree to differ. The OP seems to have *erroneously* extrapolated the meaning ***stop*** from the cited verb usage ***mask***. It's perfectly true that masks *can* "stop" certain things, but ***that's the wrong track*** for the current context. Nevertheless, learners would face an impossible task if they had to commit to memory every different sense of a metaphoric usage *without relating it to **other** metaphoric usages of the same base concept*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Well, it's not like this answer is going to run out of characters if it has a little more explanation added to it. Answers on SE aren't for learners to memorize, but to use as a reference.